# Isomorphism of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)/\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$ to $K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, trace, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)$ be the general linear Lie algebra over a field $K$ and $\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$ the special linear Lie algebra over $K$.

I have to show that the quotient $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)/\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$ is
isomorphic to the onedimensional abelian Lie algebra.

I know that this abelian Lie algebra is isomorphic to $K$ itself, so I have
to find an isomorphism of the quotient to $K$.

I think it has something to do with the trace $$tr:\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)/\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)\rightarrow K,$$

but I can't see if this is an isomorphism.

Any help or advice is very much appreciated!

Comment: Just consider the trace map $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)\to K$ and use the first isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel of $\operatorname{tr}\colon\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)\longrightarrow K$ is $\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$ and its range is $K$. Therefore, it induces a Lie algebra isomorphism from $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)$ onto $K$.

Comment: To be pedantic, one could add that $tr([A,B])=0$ for all $A,B \in \mathfrak{gl}_n(K)$, which shows (more than) that $tr$ is indeed a homomorphism *of Lie algebras*.

Comment: Yes. That's a good point.